# Telling IntelliJ IDEA which methods not to identify as unused

Tags: java, spring, annotations, intellij-idea, aop

IntelliJ IDEA has a handy feature to detect unused methods and show them in grey, hinting a potential warning for dead code.

Some methods, however, are not executed directly but via reflection. A good example would be `@RequestMapping`-annotated methods which are executed by Spring. IntelliJ has decent Spring integration hence it detects this annotation and does not mark such a method as unused.

I have a tiny AJAX framework where I use my own annotation to point which method to execute based on certain HTTP request properties (very similar to what `@RequestMapping` is doing). Understandably, IntelliJ has no idea what does my annotation stand for and and marks such a method as unused, adding unnecessary noise.

I was thinking of:

- annotating my annotation with another annotation, but are there any standard ones that would do the job without any extra effort?
- finding a particular setting in IntelliJ to identify custom annotation for marking methods as used, but this would require other team members to do the same, basically a pain.

Can anyone suggest any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can tell IntelliJ to not to warn about used for any method/field annotated with the annotation the "unused" method has.

It should be a quick fix all you have to do is hit <Alt>+<Enter> and select `Suppress for methods annotated by ...`

You don't need to add anything to you code and you only have to do this once per annotation.

[image]

Comment: unfortunately I do not have this option, my annotation is `@WebMethod` and I am using Intellij 14.1.1 . Any idea why I do not have this option available?

Comment: This works with recent versions like a charm. IntelliJ really comes with some magic.

Comment: I've accidentally suppressed this for "fields annotated with xx". To undo this operation find `<component name="EntryPointsManager">` in the `.idea/misc.xml` file and adapt it (don't forget to update the `list` attribute, when you change the count of items)

Comment: Maybe this action is hidden at the "More actions..." link at the bottom right corner in a warning's hint window

Answer (score 49):

`@SuppressWarnings("unused")` should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ideally I would want my custom annotation to be able to handle this automagically so I don't have to add @SuppressWarnings("unused") on each method. Or are you suggesting I should annotate my annotation (rather than method) itself?

Comment: No, I wasn't suggesting this. I don't know how to "tell IDEA which methods not to identify as unused" except by using the standard annotation. Peter's suggestion is nice, but requires just as many annotaions.

Comment: I think Peter's @UsedViaReflection is just a pseudo code, it can be any annotation really. It isn't ideal (as I was mentioning in my question), but I guess there are no other alternatives.

Answer (score 7):

@Peter Lawrey s solution did not help in my version of Intellij (14.1.1).

I used the hard way around:Settings-Editor->Inspections->Unused declarion
Now there is an Options point, scroll down to `Configure annotations...` and you can add your annotation there.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Settings" you can "uncheck" Settings - Inspections - Declaration redundancy - Unused Declaration code inspection.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is finding trouble with this at the moment, here is how you can configure it in IntelliJ IDEA's current version:
[Route viewn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBzLs.png)

File > Settings > Editor > Inspections > Unused declaration > Entry Points > Annotations... > Mark as entry point if annotated by

Really useful for @Beans!