# Don't show warning for unused Getters/Setters

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When a method is never used, IntelliJ shows a warning `Method xxx() is never used`

But for POJOs, I create Getters/Setters for every attributes and I do not want IntelliJ to warn me for unused Getters/Setters.

Is there a way to automatically suppress those warnings?

Comment: I am wondering, how IntelliJ could know, that a getter/setter is not used? Usually they are public! In Eclipse, we have the same kind of warning, that only pops up, when a method is private.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose IntelliJ builds a `Dependencies Structure Matrix` which enables to find every reference of a method/class/attribute etc. see https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/dependency_analysis.html#link8

Comment: Eclipse does nearly the same (it builds an AST). The main point of my comment is: You cannot know, whether your class is maybe part of a library used in other projects, where those methods are used. So you should not display a warning for an unused method that is public. It's another story if it's private.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I agree with you. IntelliJ cannot guess if the developer is making a library or an application. Hence, the developer cannot rely on it when making a library but this is extremely useful when developing an application.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose and thank you for AST. Now I understand what is this cryptic `AST Node` that I often see in exceptions :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As of IDEA 2016.3 there is a setting to do this.
Using IntelliJ on a Mac, it is under `Settings` | `Editor` | `Inspections` | `Java` | `Declaration redundancy` | `Unused declaration` | `Methods` | `Getters/setters`

[image: Disable unused getter/setter method warnings]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can annotate your methods with `//noinspection`.

You can navigate to `Settings` | `Inspections` | `Declaration redundancy` | `Unused Declarations` and define a scope for your methods but I do believe you cannot disable it for *getters/setters* only an leave other methods out of inspection.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend lowering the severity for unused methods in general. Simply go to 
Settings | Inspections | Declaration redundancy | Unused Declarations, and change the severity to "Info" or "Weak Warning" .

Answer (score 0):

You have just to hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and select `Suppress for methods annotated by ...`

[image: Where to click]

**See also:**
[Telling IntelliJ IDEA which methods not to identify as unused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283972/telling-intellij-idea-which-methods-not-to-identify-as-unused)

Comment: The Getters/Setters do not have any annotations. This forbids me to select them by annotation. But your answer solves another of my problems : suppress warnings for methods annotated with `com.google.inject.Inject`

Comment: This would mean annotating each getter/setter, so we could initially add a "suppress" annotation. It's not helpful.