# IntelliJ IDE disable 'is never used' inspection

Tags: java, intellij-idea, handler

I extends `MessageCracker` Class and override methods(Handlers)

```
public void onMessage(ExecutionReport execRep, SessionID sessionID)
...
public void onMessage(BusinessMessageReject message, SessionID sessionID)
...
public void onMessage(Quote quote, SessionID sessionID)
```

each method catch messages extend `Message` - ExecutionReport, BusinessMessageReject, Quote etc.

All work fine but IntellijIDE say on this methods - 
`Method 'onMessage(quickfix.fix44.Quote, quickfix.SessionID)' is never used`

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is the "never used" message appearing on the interface/parent or on the subclass?

Comment: If these methods are also annotated somehow, You can suppress this warning by that annotation through Alt+Enter and related additional action ( see the answer at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283972/telling-intellij-idea-which-methods-not-to-identify-as-unused/5284371#5284371 )

Answer (score 8):

IntelliJ is telling you that a public method on your class is unused. It's not an error, it's just an information message.

You could think of it as a gentle hint: by writing a public method you have implied that something should use that method but IntelliJ is unable to find any usages of that method so it warns you just in case either (a) the method scope should be reduced or (b) you have forgotten to write the code which is intended to invoke this method.

You can switch this behaviour on/off from `Preferences > Editor > Inspections > Unused Declaration`

[image]

You can also disable this inspection on a specific method/class by [annotating](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/) with [`@SuppressWarnings("unused")`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html).

Comment: There are methods that are not really used and I want to see information about them. But these methods are not explicitly called but used. They receive messages.

Comment: According to IntelliJ's "Unused declaration" inspection these methods are unused. If you disagree with IntelliJ's inspection then you can disable it, see `Preferences > Editor > Inspections > Unused Declaration`. However, it is only an information message, it does not indicate an error so you could also just ignore it.

Comment: I understand it. Perhaps there is an annotation or a way to mark methods that work like handler

Comment: You can add the `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` annotation to this method.

Comment: or (c) these are part of an api that is externally visible to projects depending on your lib. Then again, if you write tests for these the warnings will go away. The issue I run into is that every time I try to commit something I get "you have 7 warnings in this file...are you sure you'd like to commit?" And there could be a valid warning that shows up that I don't notice because of the unused method warnings.